# Combining 2 arrays of strings to create an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following data like this:

```
fields = ["player_id", "name", "team", "player_id", "name", "team", "player_id", "name", "team"]
values = ["001", "Pound", "Monstars", "002", "Bang", "Monstars", "003", "Jordan", "Looney Tunes"]
```

I want to create an array of hashes, so the data will look like this:

```
[{"player_id"=>"001", "name"=>"Pound", "team"=>"Monstars"}, {"player_id"=>"002", "name"=>"Bang", "team"=>"Monstars"}, {"player_id"=>"003", "name"=>"Jordan", "team"=>"Looney Tunes"}]
```

In my quest to improve, I think I'm still doing more steps than necessary:

```
sliced_fields = fields.each_slice(3).to_a
=> [["player_id", "name", "team"], ["player_id", "name", "team"], ["player_id", "name", "team"]]

sliced_values = values.each_slice(3).to_a
=> [["001", "Pound", "Monstars"], ["002", "Bang", "Monstars"], ["003", "Jordan", "Looney Tunes"]]

new_array = sliced_values.map { |i| Hash[sliced_fields[sliced_values.index(i)].zip(i)] }
=> [{"player_id"=>"001", "name"=>"Pound", "team"=>"Monstars"}, {"player_id"=>"002", "name"=>"Bang", "team"=>"Monstars"}, {"player_id"=>"003", "name"=>"Jordan", "team"=>"Looney Tunes"}]
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your desired output doesn't make sense. You want three hashes of identical information?

Comment: @theTinMan sorry, I edited the desired result, and realized my solution produced identical information like you said, so removed that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. `zip` first, then `each_slice`:

```
fields.zip(values).each_slice(3).map(&:to_h)
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/I7S3